# Is there any lower bound for basis computation in finite Abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Victor Shoup in [this](https://www.shoup.net/papers/dlbounds1.pdf) paper has given a lower bound for discrete logarithm. The algorithms that I have come across use discrete logarithms (extended discrete logarithms) to compute a basis for a finite Abelian group. For instance, in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3413.pdf) paper Andrew Sutherland gives a probabilistic algorithm that computes a basis of finite abelian group $G$ using an expected $O(|G|^{1/2})$ group operations. Is it known if there exists a lower bound on basis computation or if the computation of basis is in general tougher than computing discrete logarithms for generic groups?

Comment: This may be worth asking on Math Overflow if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Sure. Ill post it there too. Thanks